# Изменение регистра в массиве.

Tags: javascript

Нужно заменить все фамилии,начинающиеся с маленькой буквы,на те же фамилии,только начинающиеся с заглавной,т.е. поменять регистр первой буквы. В чём ошибка?  
    <script>

```
var a=["бердяев","Афанасенко","савельев"];
document.write("Input:<br>");
document.write(a+"<br><br>");

for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
  if ((a[i].charAt(0))==['а-я'])
```

`` { a[i] = a[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();}
          else continue;
   }
      document.write("Output:<br> "+a);

```
</script>
```

Comment: Что значит `a[i].charAt(0))==['a-z']`? (1) " бердяев" -- первый символ -- пробел

Comment: Убрал пробелы,и исправил ['a-z'] на ['а-я'], т.к. русские буквы. В итоге всё равно отказывается переводить в верхний регистр.

Comment: То есть сравниваете первый символ со строкой '[а-я]'. И они не совпадают. Беда какая.

Может Вы хотели

     /а-я/.test(a[i].charAt(0))

(не самый подходящий вариант, поскольку и замену регистра можно сделать регулярными выражениями)

Comment: А смысл в проверке? Если вы знаете, что в массиве только имена/фамилии, то почему бы просто не переводить все первые буквы в верхний регистр? Не помешает еще и пробелы удалять. В общем, [вот как-нибудь так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vxraC/)

Comment: Думал как-то можно обойтись без регулярных выражений. Но,спасибо всем за ценные ответы.

Comment: @Deonis, а разве trim() уже не везде есть? В любом случае можно проще :) replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')

Comment: > а разве trim() уже не везде есть

@klopp, возможно. Не успеваю следить за всеми "тенденциями моды" ))

Comment: Скажите мне кто-нибудь, что делает логотип вебшторма в метке javascript?

Comment: @Lucky, а, так вот в чём дело! (скромно потупив глазки, вебшторм это WS? УЕБ-СТОРМ по-русски? это какая-то программа для - чего-то?)

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/4058/deonis, в как быть в случае если в массиве помимо фамилии есть ещё и имя и разделены они пробелом?В таком случае получается,что trim() не прокатит?

Comment: @GTRL, а вы код-то trim() видели? Там же на javascript по белому написано что именно удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.prototype.ucfirst = function() 
{
    var str = this;
    if(str.length) 
    {
        str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return str;
};
alert( 'LALAlala'.ucfirst() );
```

Comment: А как это адаптировать для случая с моим массивом?
Нужно просматривать элементы в цикле?

Comment: Можно и руками в цикле, а можно и так:


    Array.prototype.ucfirst = function() 
    {
        var a = this;
        for( i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            // проверки типа a[i] нет:
            a[i] = a[i].ucfirst();
        }
        return a;
    }
    alert( ['LALAlala','ZaZaZa'].ucfirst() );

Comment: Не выполняется данный код. Или я что-то забыл? http://jsfiddle.net/vxraC/1/

Comment: Конечно же не выполняется - куда пропала String.prototype.ucfirst()?

Comment: Да,всё,исправил,спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
function titleCase(str) {
var arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');

var result = arr.map(function(val){
return val.replace(val.charAt(0), val.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
});
return result.join(' ');
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Оставлю это здесь.
Может пригодиться кому-то)

Comment: Вы несомненно повысите качество ответа, если вместо лишённого информации эпилога добавите пару пояснений к вашему фрагменту кода.